# Display form inline HTML

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/?page_id=19

I tried to put in line forms "subject" and "email" but we did not ... how can I fix this?

I used Wordpress and CForm Builder plugin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code here, clarify what you want. Just linking it is to enough. Without any additional information your question may be closed! see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: If you don't show us your code, and don't define your problem, how do you expect us to help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with style, add this style to your style.css file :

```
div[wdid="4"] {
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
}

div[wdid="22"] {
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.wdform-label-section {
    width: 50px !important;
}
```